# I am getting an error in a simple sns barplot, how do i get past it?

Tags: dataframe, web-scraping, bar-chart, visualization, data-analysis

I'm trying to generate a visualization of a little data frame

`df = df[:20,]`

chicken          11
chickenrepubl     8
republ            8
2023              8
aug               7
of                6
to                5
convers           4
plate             3
imag              3
see               3
you               3
what              3
and               2
than              2
pot               2
a                 2
meal              2
citizen           2
tweet             2
Name: count, dtype: int64

then i tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha=0.8)

plt.title('Top Words Overall')
plt.ylabel('Word from Tweet', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Count of Words', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

but i got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 6
      4 df = df[:20,]
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
----> 6 sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha=0.8)
      8 plt.title('Top Words Overall')
      9 plt.ylabel('Word from Tweet', fontsize=12)

TypeError: barplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will result

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.values, alpha=0.8)
```

[image: output]

and also trying to work in a way to add

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

to get this type of result.

[image: output2]